# React-native firebase Signinwithemal and createuserwithemailandpassword

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native

i am trying to make a simple login app, when you try to login with an account that isnt registered, it should just make a new account.

Like you can see on my onButtonPress function, my problem is that whatever i try to fill in, i get the error message. Which doesnt make sense, normally if i would fill in an email-adres and password for the first time, it should just register me, but instead of that, i just always get the error message.

Here you can see my LoginForm class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
state = { email: '', password: '', error: '' };

onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .catch(() => {
                    this.setState({ error: 'Authentication failed' });
                });
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <Input 
                    placeholder="user@gmail.com"
                    label="Email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                />
            </CardSection>
            <CardSection>
                <Input
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder="password"
                    label="Password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                />
            </CardSection>
            <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
                {this.state.error}
            </Text>
            <CardSection>
                <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                    Log in
                </Button>
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    );
}
}

const styles = {
errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red'
 }
};

export default LoginForm;
```

I will add my Input class as well, you never know what could be wrong... :)

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText, placeholder, secureTextEntry }) 
=> {
const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
        <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
        <TextInput 
            placeholder={placeholder}
            autoCorrect={false}
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            style={inputStyle}
            value={value}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
        />

    </View>
 );
};

const styles = {
inputStyle: {
    color: '#000',
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 23,
    flex: 2,
    height: 40

},
labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    flex: 1

},
containerStyle: {
    height: 40,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
}
};

export { Input };
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a .then(), only a .catch(). Maybe this can help?

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then()
```